Line2D multiple colors in legend
I want to create a custom legend. Here, in the example, I create two lines. But for this line, which now is blue, I would like it to be in multiple colors: blue, green, and red.
Here is a minimum working example:
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import matplotlib.colors
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D

LE = [Line2D([0], [0], color='crimson', lw=14, label=r'0.05'),
                   Line2D([0], [0], color='lightgrey', lw=14, label=r'$0$')]


ax1 = plt.figure()

ax1.legend(handles=LE, bbox_to_anchor=(0.55, 0.7), ncol=1, fontsize=30, frameon=False)

plt.plot(1,1)

plt.show()


